# Unable to convert implicitly to System.IDisposable when using "Using"

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

Given two interfaces like these:

```
public interface MyInterface1 : IDisposable
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public interface MyInterface2 : IDisposable
{
    void DoSomethingElse();
}
```

... and an implementation class like this:

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface1, IMyInterface2
{
    public void DoSomething()     { Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something..."); }
    public void DoSomethingElse() { Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something else..."); }
    public void Dispose()         { Console.WriteLine("Bye bye!"); }
}
```

... I'd assume the following code snippet should compile:

```
class Program
{
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
          using (MyInterface1 myInterface = new MyClass()) {
              myInterface.DoSomething();
          }
     }
}
```

... instead I always get the following error message:

```
Error  1  'IMyInterface1': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you've typed everything correctly? You have `MyInterface1` and `MyInterface2` at the top, but `IMyInterface1` and `IMyInterface2` later on.

Comment: @j3d - please post _accurate_ code only. Verify it before posting.

Comment: As written above, we get *other* compilation errors, not the one you describe. However, the way you wrote the types above, each of the interface types (in itself) is implicitly convertible to `IDisposable`.

Comment: Is you real problem that the class type can be converted to `IDisposable` in two distinct ways, through different interfaces implemented?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - No, MyClass only implements it once. The 2 branches are folded, what C++ calls virtual inheritance.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, I was wrong. The only time it may matter to "re-implement" an interface is when you have a base **class** which already supplies one (explicit) implementation of the interface. That situation is entirely unrelated to the actual question as it stands.

Answer (score 4):

Works correctly

```
public interface IMyInterface1 : IDisposable
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public interface IMyInterface2 : IDisposable
{
    void DoSomethingElse();
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface1, IMyInterface2
{
    public void DoSomething() { Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something..."); }
    public void DoSomethingElse() { Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something else..."); }
    public void Dispose() { Console.WriteLine("Bye bye!"); }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (IMyInterface1 myInterface = new MyClass())
        {
            myInterface.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

you just forgot to make `Dispose()` public, and the name of the interfaces was wrong (`MyInterfaceX` instead of `IMyInterfaceX`)

Ideone: http://ideone.com/WvOnvY

Comment: His question is bad, but what happens if you use `var` in the `using` declaration?!

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It works correctly.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen All the variations, with var, to one or the other interface, to MyClass. http://ideone.com/cueYt1

Comment: Have you tried it? EDIT: Hmm, I see you have. Maybe I will retract my answer then.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I only have a Visual Studio that compiled correctly and an ideone with the output. And I even gave you the ideone link. Do you need a screenshot?

Comment: You are right, of course. My theory about what his real problem could have been, was wrong, maybe an impossible theory. I have deleted my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should (also) have seen a compiler error about `Dispose()` not being public.

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface1, IMyInterface2
{
    public void DoSomething()     { Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something..."); }
    public void DoSomethingElse() { Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something else..."); }
    void Dispose()                { Console.WriteLine("Bye bye!"); }
}
```

The `Dispose()` method in this class cannot be implementing `IDisposable`, so there must be something more going on.